# POST json object in a form variable on a sever

Tags: php, ios, arrays, json, swift

hello I am working on IOS SWIFT 2. I NEED to send the json object in a variable so that I can access the json object like that

```
$json = $_POST['json'];

        $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
        $email         = $data['email'];
        $user_password = $data['password'];
```

right now the data is posting on server like this

```
{
  "email" : "email",
  "password" : "password"
}
```

This is the code I am using

```
func post() {
         let url:String = "http://example.com/test.php"

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
         let params = ["email":"email", "password":"password"] as Dictionary<String, String>

        //let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        do {

            let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)
            let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            print("dataString is  \(dataString)")
            request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)


        } catch {
            //handle error. Probably return or mark function as throws
            print(error)
            return
        }
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            // handle error
            guard error == nil else { return }

            print("Response: \(response)")
            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Body: \(strData)")

            let json: NSDictionary?
            do {
                json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
            } catch let dataError {
                // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
                print(dataError)
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
                // return or throw?
                return
            }


            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            if let parseJSON = json {
                // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                let success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
                print("Succes: \(success)")
            }
            else {
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
            }

        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

I want to  pass the json above in a form variable called 'json'.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using a Library, such as [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to handle this.
Doing it yourself is tedious.

Once added to your Swift Project, you can send JSON parameters really, really elegantly:

*Example from the Github page:*

```
let parameters = [
    "foo": [1,2,3],
    "bar": [
        "baz": "qux"
    ]
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
```

Then you can use your existing PHP code to process your JSON.

Edit:

Also handling JSON is really elegant too:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, etc).responseJSON { response in
             print(response.request)  // original URL request
             print(response.response) // URL response
             print(response.data)     // server data
             print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

             if let JSON = response.result.value {
                 print("JSON: \(JSON)")
             }
         }
```